# accessing values of selected item in AutoCompleteTextView's CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, custom-adapter

I am attempting to populate a `autocompletetextview` by getting a list of countries from server in form of list. 
I have been able to populate the `autocompletetextview` with `customAdapter`. However,I have had difficulty finding a way to access other values of the selected item in object such as `id`, and `defaultCurrencyId`

my Country object:

```
public class Country {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private Integer defaultCurrencyId;
private String phonePrefix;
private Integer status;
private Object deletedAt;
private String createdAt;
private String updatedAt;

... standard getter and setter ...

}
```

I am using `name` to show in the list. and i need to get the `id` of the selected `name`.

my Custom **CountryAdapter**:

```
    public class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {
    private final String MY_DEBUG_TAG = "CountryAdapter";
    private ArrayList<Country> items;
    private ArrayList<Country> itemsAll;
    private ArrayList<Country> suggestions;
    private int viewResourceId;

    public CountryAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId, ArrayList<Country> items) {
        super(context, viewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.itemsAll = (ArrayList<Country>) items.clone();
        this.suggestions = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.viewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(viewResourceId, null);
        }
        Country country = items.get(position);
        if (country != null) {
            TextView countryNameLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
            if (countryNameLabel != null) {
//              Log.i(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "getView Country Name:"+country.getName());
                countryNameLabel.setText(country.getName());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return nameFilter;
    }

    Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = ((Country)(resultValue)).getName();
            return str;
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if(constraint != null) {
                suggestions.clear();
                for (Country country : itemsAll) {
                    if(country.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        suggestions.add(country);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            ArrayList<Country> filteredList = (ArrayList<Country>) results.values;
            if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Country c : filteredList) {
                    add(c);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

In my  **Activity:**

```
public void setCountryAdapter(ArrayList<Country> country){

        CountryAdapter countryAdapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view_row, country);
        _actvCountry.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

}
```

I attempted to use `OnItemSelectedListener` which gives the position of the selected item. but i was wondering if it is possible to access other variables in Country Object. as I adapted the CustomAdapter for this purpose.

Please let me know if you need more elaboration on the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use: `setOnItemClickListener` in `autoCompleteTextView` and retreive the custom object. Like:

```
  autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
        Country  country  = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String id = country.getId();
        //other information
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was the exact solution.